# How to use if loop with sql-php condition?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, if-statement

I tried to pass value through HTML form and check the condition as mentioned below.

In HTML:

```
<form name="Nurse" action="nurse_display.php" method="get">
    <b>Nurse_id:</b>
    <select name="nurse_id">
        <option value="N001">01</option>
        <option value="N002">02</option>
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Date:</b>
    <select name="date">
        <option value="2014-05-01">May 01, 2014</option>
        <option value="2014-05-02">May 02, 2014</option>
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value=" View Schedule">
</form>
```

In PHP:

```
$nurse_id=$_GET["nurse_id"];
$date =$_GET["date"];
if(($nurse_id='ALL') && ($date='ALL'))
{
...
}
else{
...
}
```

Even if i click particular nurse id with date, all nurse details are getting displayed.

Comment: when you're testing you should use `==`  One `=` is for assignment... i.e. `($nurse_id=='ALL') && ($date=='ALL')`

Comment: it is working aftr i changed the if condition to this if(($nurse_id=='ALL') && ($date=='ALL'))    thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use the comparison operator `'=='`

Code:

```
if( ($nurse_id == 'ALL') && ($date == 'ALL') )
{
    ...
}
else{
    ...
}
```